# Installing a linux distro directly from an iso on hard disk, with windows 8.1 installed?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, installation, iso-image

I'm trying to install Ubuntu directly from the iso image I downloaded, without burning it to a DVD or flashdrive, following instructions from [this article](http://www.instantfundas.com/2007/08/install-any-linux-distro-directly-from.html) (I have Windows 8.1 installed). This involves modifying windows' boot.ini file. The article is from 2007, however, and as far as I know [Windows has changed from using boot.ini since Vista to Boot Configuration Data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista_startup_process#Boot_Configuration_Data). I wonder if there is any way to make this still work? Thank you in advance.

By the way, I don't have a DVD-drive, and buying a flashdrive is a bit expensive for me now [*insert broke college student joke here*], so this is the only way I know of to get Ubuntu installed.

Comment: I guess WUBI (windows ubuntu installer) won't work since you're on Win8.. without any way to "boot" from the ISO (which is using CD/DVD / USB disc) your only option I know is install Ubuntu as Virtual Machine (using virtualbox or similar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using linux with Windows 8 could be different from older Windows versions, things like EFI/UEFI and Secure Boot need some special attention. See this question on [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported).

It *should* be possible to install GRUB ([GNU bootloader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB))onto your hard drive, and have it load the Ubuntu ISO directly from the hard drive too. I haven't installed GRUB from Windows myself, but according to a google search for "[install grub from windows](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=install%20grub%20from%20windows)" it looks possible. And here are some links & very brief directions about a Multiboot USB:

- [Arch's Wiki on Multiboot USBs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multiboot_USB_drive) or [pendrivelinux.com directions for linux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-multiple-iso-from-usb-via-grub2-using-linux/), for many distros you just copy the ISO file onto the usb and edit grub.cfg. Cliff notes instructions are:

  1. Mount the usb
  2. Install grub
     `grub-install --force --no-floppy --boot-directory=/mnt/USB/boot /dev/sdx`
     (replacing x with your actual USB device & /mnt/usb with mounted dir)
  3. Put demo grub.cfg ( http://pendrivelinux.com/downloads/multibootlinux/grub.cfg ) in /mnt/USB/boot/grub and edit to match your iso's

  Or see the [Ubuntu help on creating & installing from bootable USB's](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick).

---

But, **easiest** answer would be borrowing a USB drive (preferably one with a Ubuntu iso already installed), or borrowing a dvd drive & a Ubuntu DVD would be best. Being a college student, I'd imagine there are lots of other students who have them, maybe even a computer club or linux club that could help you, or even install it with/for you, especially if it's a laptop?

PS. You'd only need a 2GB USB device to DIY, it should cost less than $5. Then you could use a http://www.pendrivelinux.com tool (like [YUMI – Your Universal Multiboot Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) or  [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)) to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

My advice, if you can't get your hands on a USB drive or a flash drive, but you still want to try Ubuntu, would be to have a look at [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Screenshots). You might already know about, in which case I'm sorry I can't be of more help. Without a USB drive or flash drive, I don't think that there is an easy way to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8, especially if we're talking about UEFI and GPT partition scheme.